# how can variables be accessed from both main() and the IRQ() functions?

Tags: microcontroller, interrupt

I'm studying for a test next week and we're learning about microcontrollers.  We just did a sample code with interrupts and it told them temperature in F and C when we pushed a button (interrupted). how can C and F be accessed from both
main and the IRQ() functions?

Comment: Make it global? Your second question depends on the microcontroller and can not be answered without knowing the type. You should read about it in the datasheet.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way to share a variable between IRQ handlers and the main thread on any bare metal system:

- Make sure that the variable type is one
  which the CPU can atomically read and write.
- Make the variable global and declare it `volatile`, so that
  the generated machine code cannot optimize away accesses to
  the shared variable.

  To read a value, use something like `const atomic_type local_copy = shared_variable;` and work with that local copy. An expression like `shared_variable * shared_variable` might use different values for `shared_variable`.
- Make sure that only one IRQ handler (which must only run once
  at the same time), or only the main thread writes to the shared variable.

  All other parts of the code are only allowed to read the shared
  variable.

If the data you want to communicate between IRQ handler and main thread does not fit inside an atomic type, have fun with complex locking protocols.